# how to populate contact counts from all contacts in landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, contactbuilder

I would like to populate the contact counts from All Contact in landing page, is there any system data view for all contact.

Regards,
Ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific data view that serves this purpose, but if you have Mobile Connect enabled in your account you can extract the data this way:

1. Create a filtered list in Mobile Connect with a single condition `Contact Key is not null`
2. Create a data extension with a single column: `SubscriberKey`
3. Query the filtered list and send the results to your data extensions: `Select SubscriberKey from [YourMobileConnect list name from step 1]`

(This process is a reverse-engineered from an article that shows how to remove unwanted customers: [Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&type=1&mode=1))

Comment: I recently learned that the reason for this is that Contact Builder Lists (Mobile Connect/Push Lists) create a hidden Data Extension with the template type "AudienceBuilderResult". That's why the querying works even though it's a "list".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But even though the Mobile Connect is enabled, i dont think it will give me all the contact counts from **All Contact** @Rafal, Is there any function in ampscript, API or SSJS, that might help me retrieve the counts?@Rafal

Comment: @Joey You would just need to use the COUNT function in the SQL in the query I listed in step 3 - this will get you a number that SSJS or Ampscript can extract from a data extension.

Comment: @Rafal i have accomplished it... thank you for your inputs.. the records are matching:)

Comment: @Rafal instead of using query as mentioned in the 3rd step can we directly access the list, is there any function which we can use to refresh the list and directly use the counts from the list rather than data extension

Comment: @Joey I don't think it's possible to extract aggregate data like the total contact count from a list. As for refreshing the list, you can use the 'Refresh Mobile Filtered List' block in Automation Studio just before the query is run.